# How to download data from JSON to table view when JSON is an Array of Dictionary?

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and learning about how to download JSON data into a table view. The code does not show any error on compile time but show on run time. Link of JSON data: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! show
        let loadingInBackground = DispatchQueue(label: "loadingInBackground", qos: .background)

        loadingInBackground.async {

            let stringURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
            let urlFromString = URL(string: stringURL)

            var request = URLRequest(url: urlFromString!)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"

            let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
            session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

                do {
                    let dataInJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [ [String: Any] ]

                    print(dataInJSON)

                    let arrayOf_dataInJSON = dataInJSON[indexPath.row]

                    cell.id.text = arrayOf_dataInJSON["id"] as! String?
                    cell.email.text = ("email: \(arrayOf_dataInJSON["email"] as! Int?)")

                }catch{print(error)}

                }.resume()
        }
        return cell
    }


}

class show : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var id: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var email: UILabel!
}
```

The error is: "**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10e7c1540) to 'NSString' (0x10b679c40)**"

I am getting error on the line: "**cell.id.text = arrayOf_dataInJSON["id"] as! String?**"

Comment: `"id": 1` is a number, you force-cast it to a string, what do you expect to happen other than a crash?

Comment: please tell me how can i solve this @luk2302

Comment: well I am new to this @NiravD.

Comment: @RajeevKulariya Try like this `cell.id.text = "\(arrayOf_dataInJSON["id"] as? Int ?? 0)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it `"\(arrayOf_dataInJSON["id"] as? Int ?? 0)"`

Comment: Thanks @Salman, the app is running fine but sometimes it just crashes and gives error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" on the line where I have used 'JSONSerialization'. What Should I do now?

Comment: @RajeevKulariya      `let dataInJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [ [String: Any] ]`

Comment: I don't know who downcasted the answer and what do you mean by "show the code where you hit the service"

Comment: I know that but, here we can give the reference you have to understand this the user know it when it comes with the optional.
we assume that the questionnaire has basic understanding about language..!!!!

Comment: @EricAya when you were born, did you started to run in a minute or what? I am new to IOS and I am still learning. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
it "\(arrayOf_dataInJSON["id"])"
```

this will display Optional(1),Optional(2),... Optional type so that you can unwrapping

cell.textLabel?.text = "(arrayOf_dataInJSON["id"] as! NSNumber)"

Comment: It shows this error: "can not assign value of type 'NSNumber' to type 'String?' "